# How to remove auto increment NEWID in add new row jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Please check the below code. When I submit value with "ADD NEW ROW" rows then generate/increment a new ID like

```
Array ( [p_product] => mission-impossible-5 [p_uom] => uom11 [p_rate] => 22 [p_price] => 43 [p_refcost] => 54 [p_opening] => 33 **[p_uom1]** => uom12 **[p_rate1]** => 23 **[p_price1]** => 34 **[p_refcost1]** => 44 **[p_opening1]** => 45 **[p_uom2]** => uom13 **[p_rate2]** => 34 **[p_price2]** => 5 **[p_refcost2]** => 3 [p_opening2] => 3 )
```

How can I remove NEW ID?

Please, check here is the  // Get max row id and set new id

jQuery code:

```
$("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "addr"+newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth() td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });

            var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
            c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
            c.appendTo($(td));
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add delete button and td
    /*
    $("<td></td>").append(
        $("<button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>")
            .click(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            })
    ).appendTo($(tr));
    */

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
    });
```

HTML markup:

```
<tbody> 
    <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="">
        <td data-name="p_uom">
            <input type="text" name='p_uom'  placeholder='UOM' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="p_rate">
            <input type="text" name='p_rate' placeholder='Rate' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="p_price">
            <input type="text" name="p_price" placeholder="Pirce" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="p_refcost">
            <input type="text" name="p_refcost" placeholder="Ref.Cost" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="p_opening">
            <input type="text" name="p_opening" placeholder="Opening Cost" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="del">
            <button nam"del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You mean when you delete you want to **decrement `id`**?